# Why does an OpenLayers map.getNumLayers() return 0 even though I've added a layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, javascript

When I try the following code, `OpenLayers` returns a `zero` result. What have I done wrong, here?

```
var map;

function loadMap () {

    // Based on example code: view-source:
    //     http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html

    map = new OpenLayers.Map(el);
    var googleStreetMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google('Google Street Map', 
                                                      { numZoomLevels: 20 });
    map.addLayers(googleStreetMap);
    var result = map.getNumLayers(); // Result == 0 :sad-panda:            
}
```

In the code above, I thought that the `map.getNumLayers()` should return `1` - considering i've asked to add a google street map.

Why is it returning zero, please?

UPDATE: something else to note: there is also no baseLayer :( I thought this would be the base layer???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because `addLayers` expects an array of layers.   If you just want to add a single layer, you should use `map.addLayer` instead. Or you could give `addLayers` what it wants:

```
map.addLayers([googleStreetMap]);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Also you can write `map.addLayers([layer])`.

Comment: Ha damn!!! Originally I had map.addLayers([layer1, layer2]); but removed the layer2 call .. and therefore forgot to remove the last 's'. DOH DOH DOH! Thanks heaps guys. Totally fixed the problem!